# mod-rewrite THE_REQUEST and (REQUEST_URI or REQUEST_FILE) give different filenames - why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was experimenting with mod-rewrite. I thought what I wanted was simple but I don't get the requested file's URI via REQUEST_URI. Rather the delived name is passed on.

The [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says:

> THE_REQUEST
>
> The full HTTP request
>   line sent by the browser to the server
>   (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1").
>   This does not include any additional
>   headers sent by the browser. This
>   value has not been unescaped
>   (decoded), unlike most other variables
>   below.
>
> REQUEST_URI
>
> The resource requested
>   in the HTTP request line. (In the
>   example above, this would be
>   "/index.html".)

However the two give different file names in my tests. I have a bootstrap.php through which I wanted to send all requests. This is the test file:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['requestedURI'];
?>
```

on the .htaccess file I have:

```
### REWRITE RULES ###
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ bootstrap.php?requestedURI=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Requesting `http://localhost/test.htm` puts out: **/bootstrap.php**

if I put THE_REQUEST instead of REQUEST_URI in the .htaccess I get **GET /test.htm HTTP/1.1**

So why not settle for THE_REQUEST? Well, as soon as a query string exists things break. If I request: `http://localhost/test.htm?x=1&y=2` I get **GET /test.htm?x=1** the first ampersand breaks things. I think it should be possible to replace all ampersands in the querystring with %26 so that it would work but I did not manage so far...

So can anyone tell why REQUEST_URI fails and how to fix it or how to rewrite the ampersands to %26 in the query string?

Thanks.

EDIT: The above report applies to xampp 1.7.3 on Win 7. I tried it on a production Linux system in the meantime and there REQUEST_URI returns what it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to explicitly pass the requested URI path and query as you can access it in PHP via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Thus this should suffice:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ bootstrap.php
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. I was overcomplicating things it seems. Still it's funny that the two servers (win / linux - if that has anything to do with it) would behave differently on REQUEST_URI in the .htaccess

Comment: @C.O.: *REQUEST\_URI* in mod_rewrite is not always the originally requested URI but can also be an already rewritten one like in your case where the [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) causes an internal redirect.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked around a bit, and haven't found any good explanation why `%{REQUEST_URI}` behaves like it does in your example. The most common way to achieve what your're after seems to be backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ bootstrap.php?requestedURI=$1 [L]
```

*Edit*

Based on your comment, it seems like `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` are updated and re-evaluated when the rewriterule is triggered.

Comment: I didn't mention REQUEST_FILENAME above but using it in my example  puts out: D:/Web_Root/bootstrap.php. You extract the filename from that so it just puts out bootstrap.php. It does exactly the same as using REQUEST_URI. It puts out "bootstrap.php" which is the file redirected to instead of the originally requested file's name... odd.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I believe is happening - have you tried using a backreference instead?

Comment: I can report the same. In some configurations `%{REQUEST_URI}` seems to be altered.